# When creating a ContraintLayout.LayoutParams object, why is the new keyword not used?

Tags: java, android

This might be a stupid question but, from my limited knowledge, when creating objects, the new keyword is needed, unless you're using reflection.

```
'''
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
'''
```

In the above example, no errors occur, so I'm just confused on what's really going on.

Comment: I'm honestly not familiar with this library, but it just appears that `getLayoutParams` is returning an existing object. `(ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)` is just a type cast; that's not creating an object. Also note that even if `getLayoutParams` was returning a newly created object, it could be using `new` for you, so its use is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Android initializes and creates a new LayoutParams object for your View when you start the application.

Answer (score 0):

When your activity that you wrote this code in it is running, in this line of code compiler create a object from ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams type that you call it params and then all attribute(from xml code or java) of **view** copy in param and you can use it in another view alse you can change it....